# Using Java Web Start

Tags: java

So I have a jar file created by Netbeans.

I would like to deploy it as a web start application but don't know how to procede.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a application project in NetBeans, you can right-click on the project and choose "Build JNLP", and then you get a war-file you can deploy in an application server.

If not, you can create your own JNLP-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://something.com/foobar" href="foobar.jnlp">

<information>
    <title>Foo Bar</title>
    <description>hello</description>
</information>

<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>

<resources>
    <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="foobar.jar" />
</resources>

<application-desc main-class="foo.bar.MainClass" />
```

and deploy the JNLP and the (signed) jar-file.

Comment: <3 Netbeasns why would you use anything else

Comment: after right clicking on the project in Netbeans IDE I can't find any "Build JNLP". Please clarify

Comment: It has to be a NetBeans Module application, ie if you choose File->New Project->NetBeans Modules->(Module Suite or NetBeans Platform Application), then you can right-click and choose "Build JNLP Application".

Answer (score 2):

See [how to deploy a JNLP application](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Java Web Start Developer Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step by step instructions to distribute your application vis Java Web Start: [Distribute your Swing application via Java Web Start](http://techmindviews.blogspot.com/2010/08/java-swing-web-start-jnlp.html)